# Remove left alignment of MUI Select Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, drop-down-menu

How to remove the left alignment that is occurring in the MUI Select Drop down list.

I want to remove the gap between the left red and green border. And align my dropdown directly under the MUI Select Component. How to do it?

[image]